# Как разделить колонки в гриде добавив отступы между ними?

Tags: bootstrap, vue.js

На странице имеется футер, а так же грид, но не понимаю как разделить колонки добавив отступы между ними. Макет подобный 4х16.

Comment: Вам нужно привести пример вашего кода, иначе ничего не понятно.